# Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have an update stored procedure, I call it from c# code and my code is running in 3 threads at the same time. Update statement generally throws the error "Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction". How can I solve this in sql server 2014 or in c# code?

Update stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_UpdateSP
@RecordID nvarchar(50),
@FileNetID nvarchar(50),
@ClassName nvarchar(150) 

 AS

Begin tran t1
UPDATE MYTABLE SET FilenetID=@FileNetID, DOCUMENT_TYPE=@ClassName, CONTROLID='FileAttach' where OTRECORDID=@RecordID 
Commit tran t1
```

Table Index:
Non-Unique, Non-Clustered OTRECORDID Ascending nvarchar(255)

Thanks

Comment: This procedure does not cause any deadlock alone. Are you using this table in any other procedure or query in the threads?

Comment: Do not start your procedure names with `sp_`. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: You say `otrecordid` is `nvarchar(255)`. Why is the parameter for `@RecordId` `nvarchar(50)` ?

Comment: Would need the complete table DDL including indexes and the execution plan to really see what's going on.  Is this UPDATE expected to affect multiple rows?  If not why is there no unique index on OTRECORDID?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is caused by SQL performing a scan over the table because it thinks that is quicker than doing a seek on the index and then a keylookup to find the row to update.

You can prevent these scans and force SQL to perform a seek by using the `FORCESEEK` hint.

You code would become

```
Begin tran t1
UPDATE mt SET FilenetID=@FileNetID, DOCUMENT_TYPE=@ClassName, CONTROLID='FileAttach' FROM MYTABLE mt WITH(FORCESEEK) where OTRECORDID=@RecordID 
Commit tran t1
```

This will be slower than the scan but will reduce the probability of deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the exact answer, but if you want a workaround to skip the problem, run services:

Win + R > type services.msc

Find SQL Server service - Mostly named SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) if you have only one instance - then Restart the service, now the deadlocked transaction has gone so you can keep working.